# MVC4 AJAX dynamic images - Google Chrome MIME type text/javascript

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

My application is developed in MVC4 C#, I generate images dynamically using the following:
Controller:

```
                      .....                    
                      using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            objImage.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Png);
                            data = this.File(memStream.GetBuffer(), "image/png");
                        }
                        ......
```

View:

```
        image.src = '/Home/GenerateImage?' + $.param({
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            async: true
        });
```

Works great in IE, Safari, and FireFox.  The image does not show in Google Chrome, using the developer tool, I found this error:

```
Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/javascript
```

I would appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with MIME Type, I am using session variables and cookies was disabled.